# Given a domain instance, findAll() hasMany objects with boolean query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a class A, mapped with a recursive has many relationship.  (A has many A).  The A class has a boolean attribute "islocked".  If I have an instance of class A, how can I find all of A's descendants that have islocked == 1.

```
static hasMany = [children:A]
```

This would give me all the A that have islocked == true

```
A.findAll(islocked== true);
```

I want the same functionality given an instantiated A as such:

```
def instantiated_A = A.get(1);  //Grab an instance
def descendants = instantiated_A.what_should_I_call_here(); // What should I do here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to find out children with `isLocked` true? If yes, you can use `where` query as below:

```
A.where { id == 1 && children.isLocked }.children.list()
```